# How to establish remote connection to IIS 7.5 server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, iis-7.5

i have bit dumb question, but i need to be sure before i will sent ticket to my IT or he will eat me alive. I have windows server, where is running IIS 7.5. Is it possible to establish remote connection to this server? I found [this manual](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/remote-administration/configuring-remote-administration-and-feature-delegation-in-iis-7) and just wana to clarify some minor questions. Like to remote administrate IIS do i need IIS 7.5 on my workstation too? (realy dumb question but i need to be sure) and is it enough? Or are here some glitches?

Comment: Maybe its rdp :) i just need to have access to IIS 7.5 configuration, which is now only posible via remote desktop and admin login (but admin dont wana to gave me full access to server, so i need to establish remote access only for IIS)

Answer (score 1):

I RDP into my W2008 and W2012 servers to do admin work as you describe. Both of them also run different versions of IIS.

Depending on the account you log in with will depend on your access rights (as you'd expect).

However, if you're accessing the config file then do you mean the config file of your web application... If so, you have that already in your ASP.NET project (assuming you're using ASP.NET (WebForms or MVC)), the web.config file (s)!

Comment: thanks, i will response to your answer as soon as IT give me feedback. And about web.config file, its kinda weird, but i have php server on IIS (dont smash me with newspapers its not on my choice)